# How does SO really work for new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I've been reading Stack Overflow for many years and I've been pleased with the range and quality of answers. Now that I have some more unusual problems I find SO pretty convenient but compared to my expectations it is rather disappointing. The answers to my questions were OK, the threshold was usually high enough to keep the rubbish at bay.

Overall I have figured out that this is a very bad time for new users to sign up. Gaining some useful reputation is harder than it should be, appearantly there is an army of F5 pressers that answer any question no matter the quality of the question or their answer. What makes matters worse is that rep harvesting users seem to validate each others laziness by upvoting while practically ignoring new users. I leave open whether this is completely true but to me such mentality is pretty depressing. I can't imagine how this is worth a noob his time without spending all day on SO. As good as all of my rep up till now has been earned by asking new questions, I honestly find very few questions that aren't duplicates and most are simply too hopeless to answer.

Rep isn't really a big deal though. Good users will always answer good questions no matter who asks, but I wish SO had more to offer than that for new users at this time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more to offer" (or what you want to discuss, really).

Comment: Looking at your SO participation, 4 of your answers were made very recently (today/yesterday). They might gain votes if the prove to be good enough. 1 answer to an old question got you 3 upvotes. Another answer seemingly didn't apply to the OP's situation and the last one is just a slab of code. For what you've posted you seem to be doing just fine in terms of reputation. This is not a race. Stick to it, provide ever better answers, and you'll do just fine.

Comment: @Mat With more to offer I mean more opportunity to do something useful aside from personal projects.

Comment: @toplel32: could you provide an example - sorry for being dense, but I don't see what sort of stuff you'd think would be a good thing to add to SO.

Comment: @Bart The old question had a bounty back then, therefore my answer quickly got some attention.

Comment: Yep @toplel32. I don't see any reason for concern in your contributions and their evaluation though.

Comment: Is it just me who finds it ironic that this question has been marked as a duplicate???

Answer (score 1):

> appearantly there is an army of F5 pressers

In my opinion, even if there are some people that use auto-refresh and scan over to see interesting questions, this effect is most likely caused by the immense community.

From my experience, for common-level questions you usually have 3-5 minutes to formulate an answer. For interesting questions you have more depending on how interesting it is.

Usually every answer starts small and tries to be clear. Then it is edited to add additional information or take in account the other users recommendations (this doesn't mean copying other people answers and saying that it was yours).

> I honestly find very few questions that aren't duplicates

This is quite true for popular tags. For less popular ones or new ones, there will be nice questions. Also, the questions that have a bounty are most of the time interesting and I personally read them and the answers for learning purposes if I can't help in answering them.

---

From my experience of getting started (a month ago or so) to answer questions, things were not that hard. I just gave my best to formulate the answer as good as I could.

This included:

- when I added code-snippets, I tried to explain all important parts as if I was teaching a friend
- if I was wrong about something I would accept it and correct it
- if I added an external reference I would cite from it

I am sure there were already mentioned by someone in better detail.

In conclusion, from a quick glance at your answers, the reputation gain - quality ratio is good. If you compare *StackOverflow* to an MMORPG game, you will most likely see the same effect where newbies get less *experience* (reputation) and have less *fighting power* (answering experience).